# Autolayout and CGAffineTransform

Tags: ios, catransformlayer

I am trying to scale a UIView during user interaction and I implemented the CGAffineTransform on the view as follows:

```
@implementation Tileview
{
CGAffineTransform _tempTransform;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
_tempTransform = self.transform;
self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, 1.2, 1.2);
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
self.transform = _tempTransform;
}
```

This seemed to scale the view well but I noticed later that I started to have unpredictable results when moving views around on the screen, and doing some research I learned that this is possibly because I am using autolayout.  The recommendation was to animate the layer rather than the view object.

So I attempted to refactor the above code to use `CATranform3D` becauseit seemed that the `CAAffineTransform` could not be applied to the layer.  But a `CATransform3D` could be.  But I haven't been able to figure out how to make the layer scale using that Transform object.

I have attempted to apply a transform to the View's layer as follows:

```
self.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 0.0f);
```

And that scales all the sublayers of my view

But I try to apply that to

```
 self.layer = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 0.0f);
```

I get an error saying

> Assignment to readonly property

I also looked at the `CATransformLayer` class, but when try to assign that to self.layer I get an error saying:

> Assignment to CATransformLayer from incompatible type CATransform3D

So my question is, is there a way to scale the UIView's layer without interfering with the Autolayout coordinants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using sublayer transform? This should work:

```
self.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(self.layer.transform, 1.2, 1.2, 1);
```

And also you can apply affine transforms to a layer if you really need to  via `CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(<#CGAffineTransform m#>)`

I've noticed that you are saving the initial transform to apply it after touches has ended. You can restore initial transform simply by

```
self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
```

Comment: HI Thanks for the code.  I read somewhere that the unpredictable results I was getting was because of how CGAffineTransform interacts with Autolayout and the advice was to apply the transforms to the layer not the view

Comment: The code above is correct and works.  BUT unfortunately applying the transform to the layer vs the View doesn't solve the initial problem: I'm still receiving unpredictable results when moving the views.

Comment: @LindaKeating I have some experience in this area, if you post some more code or a link to a project, I would look into it. But in a new question I suppose.

Comment: thanks for the offer.  But as I was able to rule out the autolayout/transform problem, I looked at the logic I had governing tile placement and found that some problems there that was causing the unexpected behaviour